# Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x753cb60> on <UINavigationController: 0x8293490> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am Using UINavigationController to navigate the page. When I click on submit button page needs to be redirected to the UINavigationController. Unfortunately I am getting the below error:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Here is My code Below to Navigate after clicking on Submit

```
UINavigationController *questionnaireNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DLProjectsTasksubtasks"];
        [questionnaireNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        DLProjectsTasksubtasks *qvc = (DLProjectsTasksubtasks *)[questionnaireNavController topViewController];

        [qvc.tableView reloadData];
        [self presentViewController:questionnaireNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Flow of the Page is Starting point from UINavigationController followed by a Table view, In that table view I was trying to edit the record. When I click on submit button in Add page the error occurs
Please help me out guys

Comment: it means your app needs one root view controller than you can add another view controllers to your main view.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the Solution if you dont mind?

Comment: it must be related to where you are trying to present the UINavigationController. from the look of your error, you are trying to do it inside another uinavigationController without regarding the fact that it might not be part of Main window yet. it's a pure speculation. let me know your storyboard configuration (I mean starting point and all)

Comment: Starting point is UINavigationController followed by a Table view, In that table view I was trying to edit the record. When I click on submit button in Add page the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be doing [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] ?

Comment: I guess no, COuld you please let me know how it is? As I was very new to this IOS